# How to clean up Copasi (.cps) files that became too big after leaving "create parameter set" ticked in Parameter Estimation?

Tags: xml

Copasi files can grow really large gradually by every round of Parameter Estimation if you left "create parameter set" ticked, because they save the parameter set in the file .cps file. Here is how you can clean it up by editing the .cps (~xml) file itself.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that you can remove all `ModelParameterSet`-s except the first one. In my case I went from 4mb to 100kb

#### Solution

1. Open yourmodel.cps in a `sublime text 2`.
2. Search for `ModelParameterSet_`
3. Copy everything from `<ModelParameterSet key="ModelParameterSet_1" name="Initial State">` until (and excluding) `<ListOfModelParameterSets activeSet="ModelParameterSet_2">` to another file.
4. Delete everithing between `<ListOfModelParameterSets activeSet="ModelParameterSet_1">` and `</ListOfModelParameterSets>`.

Some of these string might be slightly different per version and model, but you should find the same structure.